# Pen drive corrupted or Encrypted ? How to recover

Tags: windows, encryption, usb-flash-drive, chkdsk

My name is Manoj.

I have a 16 GB sony pendrive. When I plugged it, it shows 12 GB of it is filled. But there where no files in it. I tried even unchecking hide system files in folder options. Then I found a folder named FOUND.000 which contains FILE000.CHK to FILE312.CHK which constitutes 12 GB of memory. I am unable to delete them even in cmd diskpart. Whenever I try to format or access the pendrive, it changes from state 1 to state 2 shown in pics.. Pls help to recover my pendrive.

pic of state-1: http://screencast.com/t/1ypwYxnRdWJq

pic of state-2:  http://screencast.com/t/aAcl0XxhluDo

Answer (score 0):

Sounds corrupted, past corruption likely caused the 12gb of recovered files, and current corruption or hardware failure is causing the current "disconnects".

Recovery usually entails reading & copying any files you want to keep, if you can't read it, try mounting it read-only or another computer or with Linux (Linux Mint, Debian, Ubuntu, etc) or try a dedicated recovery program like gnu ddrescue (gddrescue) or photorec (related to testdisk).

Formatting it is a drastic way to fix filesystem errors but chkdsk/fsck should work too, but it sounds more  like a hardware problem.

If it's not bad usb hardware or your computer, it's probably the drive itself. A new one should be very cheap, only 16gb...